# mysql jdbc driver is not recognizing latin1 characters

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my current character set. I am trying to insert latin1 characters and I cant get it to work.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                             |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                            |
| character_set_connection | latin1                            |
| character_set_database   | utf8                              |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                            |
| character_set_results    | latin1                            |
| character_set_server     | latin1                            |
| character_set_system     | utf8                              |
| character_sets_dir       | /space/xyz/mysql/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

The database configuration is not created by me, so I cant change the character set or collate.

```
show create table t1;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                            |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t1    | CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `col1` text CHARACTER SET latin1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the simple code to insert a name with unicode characters.

```
private void insert() {
        try {
            loadJdbcProperties();
            String myquery = "INSERT INTO db.t1(col1) VALUES (?)";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=Cp1252";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("user", "root");
            prop.put("password", "root");
            if (_jdbcProperties != null && !_jdbcProperties.isEmpty()) {
                prop.putAll(_jdbcProperties);
            }
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);

            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String sql = null;

            sql = myquery;
            pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, "csvźà.py");
            pstmt.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the code for retrieval.

```
    private void showResults() {
        try {
            loadJdbcProperties();
            String myquery = "select col1 from db.t1";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=Cp1252";

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("user", "root");
            prop.put("password", "root");
            if (_jdbcProperties != null && !_jdbcProperties.isEmpty()) {
                prop.putAll(_jdbcProperties);
            }
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);

            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String sql = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            sql = myquery;
            pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("col1"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the result:

```
csv?à.py
```

Comment: This is because per MySQL documentation, Java-Style Character Encoding Name for latin1 is Cp1252. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Answer (score 0):

The `ź` character (Unicode code point `U+017A`) is not included in the [latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set, so MySQL cannot store it in a `latin1` column. (For the record, it's not in the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set, either.)

If you really need to store that character in that column you'll either need to

- change the column's character set to `utf8`, or
- come up with your own way to manually encode and decode the string so it can be stored as latin1 characters (e.g., something like `csv\u017aà.py`)

and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: I understand that. However, interestingly, if I use the MariaDB driver instead of MySQL driver keeping everything same, it works. I am able to store this name and get it back clean. Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Comment: What is the character encoding of your `.java` source file?